# regex expression works in Python 2.7.12, but not Python 2.7.8

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I wrote a simple script to scan a directory for a filetype (.htm), open them. and replace some text.  This script works fine on my home computer (Python 2.7.12), but not on my work computer(Python 2.7.8) and I can't figure out why.  It simply doesn't find any matches.  The files it is looking at are the same format, encoding, etc.

The expression is:

```
core = re.compile(r'(.*?)(FeatureCatalogue_Core_v??4\.\d_20[123]\d-??[01]\d-??[0123]\d)(.*?)')
```

"FeatureCatalogue_Core_v4.4_2016-12-31" should match

"FeatureCatalogue_Core_4.4_20161231" should match

"FeatureCatalogue_Core_v5.0_2017-12-31" should not match

I am sure I am missing something simple or my expression isn't quite right, but I just can't see it.

Comment: The regex is fine. There is something else that prevent correct script execution. Note you can replace all `??` with `?` and the `.` after `4` must be escaped.

Comment: As @WiktorStribiżew points out, [**your regex works**](https://regex101.com/r/6AYjjz/1) - here's an [**optimized version**](https://regex101.com/r/6AYjjz/2) as well.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.  It actually was finding matches.  My 'break' condition wasn't working.  I came up with a solution by using a counter, so after so many successful attempts it would break.

```
for x,y,z in os.walk(pathTRD):
    for doc in z:
        Path = os.path.join(x,doc)
        if Path.endswith('.htm'):
            dataR = open(Path, 'r')
            filedata = dataR.read()
            dataR.close()
            for line in filedata.split(None):
                for q in Qs:
                    mtch = re.match(q, line)
                    try:
                        Keys1.append(str(mtch.group(2)))
                        winLoop += 1
                    except:
                        pass
        if winLoop > 6:#<--- this isn't how wanted to do this, but the work computers are being dumb
                    break
        seekLoop += 1
```